# Trying to install Ubuntu from DVD get message "No operating system" and everything halts

Tags: system-installation

I know there is no operating system on my computer, I had the HD 100% wiped. I was intending for Ubuntu to be my operating system. Am I to assume I cannot install from a DVD because I have no operating system? Is there something I'm missing? I tried with Puppy Linux too, because I believed that could be operated from the disc. Same thing, "No operating system".

Comment: do you forgot to change the boot device to CD in your bios?

Comment: How did you get Ubuntu .iso onto the DVD? Did you just copy the large file onto the DVD, or did you re-create the original disk structure that the Ubuntu .iso is an image of?

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments above change the boot order from the bios so that it boots from disk first.